# SIGNALR HttpContext.Current is null

Tags: signalr

I have a question. First, excuse me for my bad english, its not my native language.
Then, I have a custom ProfileProvider, i need access to HttpCurrent.Context inside. If I call to my ProfileProvider "UserXXX.GetUserProfile" from an OperationController all is OK, but if i call it from XXXHub, HttpContext.Current is null. I was using SignalR 1.0, but i like update at version 2.0. Im using Framework 4.5, visual Studio 2012, IIS Express ith Integrated Mode and Windows 7.

Can you help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 12):

In your SignalR Hub, use:

```
System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext = Context.Request.GetHttpContext();
```

Instead of HttpContext.Current.

Comment: Works in DNN 7.x too (using `SingnalR v2.2.2`)!

Comment: `GetHttpContext()` method does not exist, where did you find that method?

Comment: @JobaDiniz depends of the .net version you are using. My answer is quite old (.net 4.5), may not apply to new .net versions.

Comment: using 4.6.2 version

Answer (score 0):

Read the [release notes](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest/release-notes). Search the section "IRequest.GetHttpContext() replacement" and implement the SystemWebExtensions class mentioned.

Comment: I am using Hub.Context and i havent problem, but if i call any method of any class HttpContext.Current is null, this not happened in older signalr version. Example: 

        XXX.dll!XXX.OperacionesChat.ContadorSalasEstado(int idArea, int idPais) Línea 497 + 0x69 Bytes C#   <--- NULL
  YYY.dll!YYY.Hubs.YYYHub.CargaContador.AnonymousMethod__37(DTO.USUARIOAREAPAISDTO tupla) Línea 174 + 0x1ca Bytes C#
  [Código externo] 
  YYY.dll!YYY.Hubs.YYYHub.CargaContador() Línea 171 + 0x52 Bytes C#
  [Código externo]

Comment: Also, my problem is not with GetHttpContext, is with HttpContext.Current. Excuse me if you dont understand me :(